# ValueError: need more than 3 values to unpack

Tags: python

I'm struggling about this `ValueError`, it happens when I want to define an `init_db` function with resetting the database and adding some data from local document (`hardwarelist.txt`), the code was:

```
def init_db():
    """Initializes the database."""
    db = get_db()
    with app.open_resource('schema.sql', mode='r') as f:
        db.cursor().executescript(f.read())
    with open('hardwarelist.txt') as fl:
        for eachline in fl:
           (model,sn,user,status)=eachline.split(',')
           db.execute('insert into entries (model,sn,user,status) values (?, ?, ?, ?)',
                          (model,sn,user,status))
    fl.close()
    db.commit()
```

And the error was:

```
File "/home/ziyma/Heroku_pro/flaskr/flaskr/flaskr.py", line 48, in init_db
    (model,sn,user,status)=eachline.split(',')
ValueError: need more than 3 values to unpack
```

What should I do?

Comment: format your code so it is readable.

Comment: you should make sure that your file contains the required number of values on each line when you split the line on `,`, like the error says.

Comment: You split a line and you don't get the expected values. You can catch that error and print the line to see what the problem is. If its valid data, you need to adjust your code to compensate. If its invalid data, you need to decide whether its a fatal error. If the garbage data leaves the whole program suspect, clean up and exit with an error.

Comment: @njzk2 thanks your advice, and I checked my document again,is was like that: a,b,c,d (every line), it seems okay?

Comment: I suggest you post an example of file that actually causes the issue?

Comment: "is was like that: a,b,c,d (every line),": probably not, or you simply looked at the wrong file. Follow tdelaney's advice, that may point you the problem quicker.

Comment: Its probably the case that you have an new line (empty) at the end of your file thats being split into `['']` and thus does not have enough to unpack.

Comment: @Evert Got it! I will try know!

Comment: @tdelaney In fact i didn't exactly catch what you mean(Sorry for my poor english) should I test my code for each line and see what would print?

Comment: @ZiyuanMa - That may be due to my explanation not your English! I will post a sample with error detection.

Comment: @AdamVanProoyen I have cleaned every block and this error still alive

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of my mentors told me "If half your code is error handling, you aren't doing enough error handling." But we can leverage python's exception handling to make the job easier. Here, I've reworked your example so that if an error is detected, a message is displayed, and nothing is committed to the database.

When you hit the bad line, its printed and you can figure out what's wrong from there.

```
import sys

def init_db():
    """Initializes the database."""
    db = get_db()
    with app.open_resource('schema.sql', mode='r') as f:
        db.cursor().executescript(f.read())
    with open('hardwarelist.txt') as fl:
        try:
            for index, eachline in enumerate(fl):
               (model,sn,user,status)=eachline.strip().split(',')
               db.execute('insert into entries (model,sn,user,status) values (?, ?, ?, ?)',
                          (model,sn,user,status))
            db.commit()
        except ValueError as e:
            print("Failed parsing {} line {}: {} ({})".format('hardwarelist.txt',
                index, eachline.strip(), e), file=sys.stderr)

            # TODO: Your code should have its own exception class
            # that is raised. Your users would catch that exception
            # with a higher-level summary of what went wrong.
            raise
```

You should expand that exception handler to catch exceptions from your database code so that you can catch more errors.

As a side note, you need to `strip` the line before splitting to remove the `\n` newline character.

UPDATE

From the comments, here's an example on splitting multiple forms of the comma. In this case its Unicode FULLWIDTH COMMA U+FF0C. Whether you can enter unicode directly into your python scripts depends on your text editor and etc..., but that comma could be represented by `"\uff0c"` or `"，"`. Anyway could can use a regular expression to split on multiple characters.

I create the text using unicode escapes

```
>>> text='a,b,c\uff0cd\n'
>>> print(text)
a,b,c，d
```

and I can write the regex with excapes

```
>>> re.split('[,\uff0c]', text.strip())
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

or by copy/paste of the alternate comma character

```
>>> re.split('[,，]', text.strip())
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

Comment: I tried just now and this error handling really told me where I should fix out! By the way that error finally be solved as I mixed up an English"," with a Chinese"," in third line,Thanks soooo much !!

Comment: Wow. That was a hard one to spot. Glad it worked!